Redshift COPY query hangs. (Running but not submitted) (Table size just 30 rows)
I have been running COPY commands on Redshift in query editor and boto3 (programatically), successfully.
However, after yesterday, neither method works.
Although, cluster console shows that query is running, stv_recents does not show the same. PG_locks shows that it is running, however there is no other table that has a lock on the concerned table. The file path exists, and I have checked that it is accessible. In case of inaccessibility, it gives an error. That is not the case here.
There is no other query running on cluster as well. I have tried to terminate the query and run again, using PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND, however it hangs everytime, until terminated.
I have tried to reboot the cluster as well. However, the same occurs.
This behavior is exclusive to load queries only. Other queries work.

Can you give a little more information?  What kind of cluster is this? Does this only happen for one table or any table? Spectrum? Is the COPY part of a larger transaction?  It sounds like a read lock but this should have been cleared by reboot.  Some process may be broken that is creating a read lock before you tried to COPY but this is just guessing.

Hi! Thank you for your comment. The cluster is a DC2Large. COPY is done using EXECUTE dynamically in a stored procedure. I have tried different tables. Different databases. Hangs.

A stored procedure runs as its own transaction.  What else is the procedure doing?  Can you post its code?  There are read locks on Redshift that are transient and can cause issues in some cases.  Knowing what else the procedure is doing could indicate if these are the issue.

The stored procedure does the following:
CREATE OR REPLACE SP AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'DELETE';
EXECUTE 'COPY';
END
But the thing is, the same stored procedure was working before, however, it suddenly stopped working.

Why are you using an EXECUTE statement.  This launches a new transaction.  I can only guess you are creating dynamic SQL and need this but if it is not needed removing could help.  The DELETE is in the parent transaction and then the COPY is in the daughter transactions so these could be fighting.  I can post a query to inspect locks including read-locks if that would be helpful.

Just posted an answer

Apparently it was a network issue. I made both the S3 bucket and Redshift cluster, publicly accessible, and the COPY command execute successfully in a few minutes.
